# Is this a conflict of interest for the lawyer

Tags: united-states, family-law, new-jersey, power-of-attorney

A lawyer, in the united states, is hired by person X to prepare her will and a medical directive giving her son the power to speak for her on medical issues (e.g. a POA for medical) if the mother cannot speak for herself. The attorney does the work and then the mother pays for the work.

After some time, the son sends an email to the attorney stating that there is reasonable evidence that the mother should be in a care facility. The son would like to put the mother in a care facility  against her wishes and would like the lawyer to handle the case. Would it be a conflict of interest for the lawyer to take the case?

Answer (score 2):

As a threshold issue, the question frames a situation in which a conflict of interest could sometimes arise. But the facts in the question really aren't rich enough for a full analysis of whether or not there is a conflict of interest.

This question is controlled (more or less entirely) by [New Jersey Rule of Professional Conduct 1.9](https://www.njcourts.gov/attorneys/rules-of-court/duties-former-clients). This states:

> Duties to Former Clients
>
> (a) A lawyer who has represented a client in a matter shall not
> thereafter represent another client in the same or a substantially
> related matter in which that client's interests are materially adverse
> to the interests of the former client unless the former client gives
> informed consent confirmed in writing.
>
> (b) A lawyer shall not knowingly represent a person in the same or a
> substantially related matter in which a firm with which the lawyer
> formerly was associated had previously represented a client,
>
> (1) whose interests are materially adverse to that person; and
>
> (2) about whom the lawyer, while at the former firm, had personally
> acquired information protected by RPC 1.6 and RPC 1.9(c) that is
> material to the matter unless the former client gives informed
> consent, confirmed in writing.
>
> Notwithstanding the other provisions of this paragraph, neither
> consent shall be sought from the client nor screening pursuant to RPC
> 1.10 permitted in any matter in which the attorney had sole or primary responsibility for the matter in the previous firm.
>
> (c) A lawyer who has formerly represented a client in a matter or
> whose present or former firm has formerly represented a client in a
> matter shall not thereafter:
>
> (1) use information relating to the representation to the disadvantage
> of the former client except as these Rules would permit or require
> with respect to a client, or when the information has become generally
> known; or
>
> (2) reveal information relating to the representation except as these
> Rules would permit or require with respect to a client.
>
> (d) A public entity cannot consent to a representation otherwise
> prohibited by this Rule.

Rule 1.9 also has [official comments](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/professional_responsibility/publications/model_rules_of_professional_conduct/rule_1_9_duties_of_former_clients/comment_on_rule_1_9/) that would be highly persuasive:

> Client-Lawyer Relationship
>
> [1](https://www.njcourts.gov/attorneys/rules-of-court/duties-former-clients) After termination of a client-lawyer relationship, a lawyer has
> certain continuing duties with respect to confidentiality and
> conflicts of interest and thus may not represent another client except
> in conformity with this Rule. Under this Rule, for example, a lawyer
> could not properly seek to rescind on behalf of a new client a
> contract drafted on behalf of the former client. So also a lawyer who
> has prosecuted an accused person could not properly represent the
> accused in a subsequent civil action against the government concerning
> the same transaction. Nor could a lawyer who has represented multiple
> clients in a matter represent one of the clients against the others in
> the same or a substantially related matter after a dispute arose among
> the clients in that matter, unless all affected clients give informed
> consent. See Comment [9]. Current and former government lawyers must
> comply with this Rule to the extent required by Rule 1.11.
>
> [2](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/professional_responsibility/publications/model_rules_of_professional_conduct/rule_1_9_duties_of_former_clients/comment_on_rule_1_9/) The scope of a "matter" for purposes of this Rule depends on the
> facts of a particular situation or transaction. The lawyer's
> involvement in a matter can also be a question of degree. When a
> lawyer has been directly involved in a specific transaction,
> subsequent representation of other clients with materially adverse
> interests in that transaction clearly is prohibited. On the other
> hand, a lawyer who recurrently handled a type of problem for a former
> client is not precluded from later representing another client in a
> factually distinct problem of that type even though the subsequent
> representation involves a position adverse to the prior client.
> Similar considerations can apply to the reassignment of military
> lawyers between defense and prosecution functions within the same
> military jurisdictions. The underlying question is whether the lawyer
> was so involved in the matter that the subsequent representation can
> be justly regarded as a changing of sides in the matter in question.
>
> [3] Matters are "substantially related" for purposes of this Rule if
> they involve the same transaction or legal dispute or if there
> otherwise is a substantial risk that confidential factual information
> as would normally have been obtained in the prior representation would
> materially advance the client's position in the subsequent matter. For
> example, a lawyer who has represented a businessperson and learned
> extensive private financial information about that person may not then
> represent that person's spouse in seeking a divorce. Similarly, a
> lawyer who has previously represented a client in securing
> environmental permits to build a shopping center would be precluded
> from representing neighbors seeking to oppose rezoning of the property
> on the basis of environmental considerations; however, the lawyer
> would not be precluded, on the grounds of substantial relationship,
> from defending a tenant of the completed shopping center in resisting
> eviction for nonpayment of rent. Information that has been disclosed
> to the public or to other parties adverse to the former client
> ordinarily will not be disqualifying. Information acquired in a prior
> representation may have been rendered obsolete by the passage of time,
> a circumstance that may be relevant in determining whether two
> representations are substantially related. In the case of an
> organizational client, general knowledge of the client’s policies and
> practices ordinarily will not preclude a subsequent representation; on
> the other hand, knowledge of specific facts gained in a prior
> representation that are relevant to the matter in question ordinarily
> will preclude such a representation. A former client is not required
> to reveal the confidential information learned by the lawyer in order
> to establish a substantial risk that the lawyer has confidential
> information to use in the subsequent matter. A conclusion about the
> possession of such information may be based on the nature of the
> services the lawyer provided the former client and information that
> would in ordinary practice be learned by a lawyer providing such
> services.
>
> Lawyers Moving Between Firms [4] When lawyers have been associated
> within a firm but then end their association, the question of whether
> a lawyer should undertake representation is more complicated. There
> are several competing considerations. First, the client previously
> represented by the former firm must be reasonably assured that the
> principle of loyalty to the client is not compromised. Second, the
> rule should not be so broadly cast as to preclude other persons from
> having reasonable choice of legal counsel. Third, the rule should not
> unreasonably hamper lawyers from forming new associations and taking
> on new clients after having left a previous association. In this
> connection, it should be recognized that today many lawyers practice
> in firms, that many lawyers to some degree limit their practice to one
> field or another, and that many move from one association to another
> several times in their careers. If the concept of imputation were
> applied with unqualified rigor, the result would be radical
> curtailment of the opportunity of lawyers to move from one practice
> setting to another and of the opportunity of clients to change
> counsel.
>
> [5] Paragraph (b) operates to disqualify the lawyer only when the
> lawyer involved has actual knowledge of information protected by Rules
> 1.6 and 1.9(c). Thus, if a lawyer while with one firm acquired no knowledge or information relating to a particular client of the firm,
> and that lawyer later joined another firm, neither the lawyer
> individually nor the second firm is disqualified from representing
> another client in the same or a related matter even though the
> interests of the two clients conflict. See Rule 1.10(b) for the
> restrictions on a firm once a lawyer has terminated association with
> the firm.
>
> [6] Application of paragraph (b) depends on a situation's particular
> facts, aided by inferences, deductions or working presumptions that
> reasonably may be made about the way in which lawyers work together. A
> lawyer may have general access to files of all clients of a law firm
> and may regularly participate in discussions of their affairs; it
> should be inferred that such a lawyer in fact is privy to all
> information about all the firm's clients. In contrast, another lawyer
> may have access to the files of only a limited number of clients and
> participate in discussions of the affairs of no other clients; in the
> absence of information to the contrary, it should be inferred that
> such a lawyer in fact is privy to information about the clients
> actually served but not those of other clients. In such an inquiry,
> the burden of proof should rest upon the firm whose disqualification
> is sought.
>
> [7] Independent of the question of disqualification of a firm, a
> lawyer changing professional association has a continuing duty to
> preserve confidentiality of information about a client formerly
> represented. See Rules 1.6 and 1.9(c).
>
> [8] Paragraph (c) provides that information acquired by the lawyer in
> the course of representing a client may not subsequently be used or
> revealed by the lawyer to the disadvantage of the client. However, the
> fact that a lawyer has once served a client does not preclude the
> lawyer from using generally known information about that client when
> later representing another client.
>
> [9] The provisions of this Rule are for the protection of former
> clients and can be waived if the client gives informed consent, which
> consent must be confirmed in writing under paragraphs (a) and (b). See
> Rule 1.0(e). With regard to the effectiveness of an advance waiver,
> see Comment [22] to Rule 1.7. With regard to disqualification of a
> firm with which a lawyer is or was formerly associated, see Rule 1.10.

There is also considerable commentary often in the form of official ethics opinions from a state attorney regulator or bar association, and case law interpreting this (which since it is largely uniform nationally includes case law from other states that is given great weight if there is no in state case law on point). The opinions and cases examine the general principles about in far more specific fact patterns which helps guide the analysis in a particular case.

Comment: Is there some detail that I can add which will enable you to give a better answer?

Comment: @Bob surely your question was purely hypothetical, right? It does not refer to a specific legal situation that you are a party to, right? Because if it was so, [it would be offtopic](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and closed as such.

Comment: @KFK My question is purely hypothetical. I am trying to educate myself.

Comment: @Bob It isn't easy to do that because so many factors could be at play: what information did the attorney learn from the client in the representation and how could that influence the current case, how long ago did it happen, were concerns about the child expressed before, what are the facts underlying the incompetency claim, would mom potentially have counterclaims/defenses particular to the son revealed in the prior representation, would the attorney be a likely witness in the new case, etc. A lot of rich detailed information is relevant in a conflict of interests analysis.